# What are the OSS .net/java projects which has utilised most SOLID Principles in a rightway?

Tags: java, .net, open-source, solid-principles

I would like to see/learn how solid principles are utilized in a right way in a real projects.

Or there is none?

Comment: They're probably all too busy arguing about SOLID rather than coding. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<shameless plug>

You can have a look at the [source code](http://github.com/orfjackal/dimdwarf) of [my project](http://dimdwarf.sourceforge.net/). I've tried to follow the SOLID principles and the recommendations of the [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) book. For example following [SRP](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) has caused the classes to be very small and focused - the largest classes are only about 200 LOC (when counting whitespace, copyright statements and comments). It's all in Java, but that is close enough to C#, and the principles are anyways the same.

</shameless plug>

Answer (score 1):

I've been pretty impressed with the work put into an open source game:  Star Trek Supremacy (http://supremacy.codeplex.com/).  In addition to the author trying to learn new technologies, he is also applying some good programming practices as well - and his code is pleasant to read (e.g. the grab a favorite beverage and a printout kind of pleasant).

The author says on the website:

> I started this project in large part
>   as a learning experience, and as such
>   it has become a sort of testbed for me
>   to try out several new Microsoft
>   .NET-based technologies, including:
>
> ```
> * WPF
> * WCF
> * LINQ (in-memory, DLINQ, and XLINQ)
> * Parallel Extensions
> * XNA (for 3D combat system)
> ```